# How to Set Admin prefix in Routing and set action for admin in any controller in ROR Like Cakephp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new in ROR i am using ruby version 1.9.3 and rails version 4.

I study ROR with cakephp its very smiler.

we have set admin prefix with Routing in cakephp.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

```
Router::connect(
    '/admin',
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true)
);
```

And we can set action for admin in any controller.

**Like :**

**//Controller File**

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function admin_index() {

        // admin_index for admin             
    }

    public function index() {

         // index for user               
    }

}
```

**//View  File**

```
Users/admin_index.ctp
Users/index.ctp
```

**My Question is how to set admin prefix in ROR and set action for admin in any controller.**

***It is possible :-***

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def admin_index
    #admin_index for admin    
  end

  def index
    #index for user    
  end

end
```

**//View  File**

```
users/admin_index.erb
users/index.erb
```

its possible or not? Please help

Comment: I removed the CakePHP tag as this is clearly not a cakephp question - regardless of the reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

write route.rb

```
namespace :admin do
 get "/users/admin_index"=> "users#admin_index"
end
```

its better if you put all controller inside admin folder under controller and then

```
class Admin::UsersController < AdminController
```

Comment: class Admin::UsersController only for admin. how to use other user? in that case i will create new other controller for other user like class UsersController < ApplicationController.

Comment: yes you should keep your admin and other user functionality in different controller . As it will be easy for you to find where your admin related code is and increase readability

Comment: you are right but it is possible or not? I want to create class UsersController < ApplicationController and define action admin_add, admin_create for admin and add and create for normal user in one controller.

Comment: i want only one controller bitween admin and normal user.

Comment: my code not setup on server. i am working on my local system.

Comment: match "/admin/index" => "users#admin_index" this will take request for http://localhost:3000/admin/index so whatever url is coming after http://localhost:3000 update that in match "/admin/index"

Answer (score 0):

for that you can create own routes in routes.rb file

```
resources :users do
 get: 'users/admin/', at: "users#admin_index", on: :collection 
end
```

Comment: class Admin::UsersController only for admin. how to use other user? in that case i will create new other controller for other user like class UsersController < ApplicationController.